# Как конвертировать curl в url?

Tags: post, curl, url

Есть запрос curl

```
curl -X POST \
  'https://test.ru/api/?USER_LOGIN=XXX&USER_HASH=XXX' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'postman-token: xxx' \
  -d '{"update":[{"id":"4657495","updated_at":"1593227040","status_id":"142","pipeline_id":""}]}'
```

Можно ли как нибудь в обычный url конвертировать?
Нужен для кнопки в почте, чтобы как ссылка была.

Answer (score 4):

Конвертировать это в URL проблемно. Ситуация в том, что это POST запрос, а не GET. Если откинуть все хедеры (-H), то получим только набор передаваемых данных в json формате.
В принципе это должно быть как:
curl -X **GET** \
  'https://test.ru/api/?USER_LOGIN=XXX&USER_HASH=XXX' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'postman-token: xxx' \
  -d '{"update":[{"id":"4657495","updated_at":"1593227040","status_id":"142","pipeline_id":""}]}'

Но опять же, если принимающая сторона понимает только POST, то о GET речи быть не может.